# Como atualizar a view após mudança na base de dados com IONIC 2

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, mobile, angular, ionic2

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com IONIC 2 onde consumo um webservice REST, de uma aplicação que está rodando online.
Na abertura da página, faço a requisição e exibo corretamente as informações na tela, porem, quando é inserido ou alterado um ítem no servidor, a view não atualiza, senão quando saio e retorno à página.

Alguns trechos de código que estão sendo utilizados:

visão:

```
<span *ngFor="#item of depoimentos">{{item.nome)}}</span>
```

Classe controladora que inicializa depoimentos:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.service.findAll().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.depoimentos = data;
    console.log(this.depoimentos);
    if (this.depoimentos.length > 0) {
      this.depoimentos[0].visivel = true;
    }
  }
)}
```

Trecho do service que faz a requisição:

```
findAll() {
    return this.http.get(depoimentosURL)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Lembrando: Estou utilizando o Ionic 2, que trabalha com o angular v2.0.0-beta.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tornar uma página real-time você deve utilizar a função timer de um Observable para realizar o refresh da página.

Por exemplo, ao iniciar a página devemos chamar a função responsável por obter os dados do serviço:

```
private timerSubscription: AnonymousSubscription;
private depoimentosSubscription: AnonymousSubscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshServico(); // função para obter dados do serviço 
}
```

Na função que chama o service para obter os dados que se deseja, deve-se chamar uma função que realizará o reload dos dados em determinado intervalo:

```
private refreshServico(): void {

       this.depoimentosSubscription = this.service.findAll().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.depoimentos = data;
            console.log(this.depoimentos);
            if (this.depoimentos.length > 0) {
              this.depoimentos[0].visivel = true;
            }
            this.subscribeDados();
          }
        );
}
```

E enfim adicionar o timer para chamar o serviço automaticamente após determinado período:

```
 private subscribeDados(): void {
    this.timerSubscription = Observable.timer(1000).first().subscribe(() => this.refreshServico()); 
}
```

Chamar a função refreshServico() a cada evento de sucesso evita que se realizem múltiplas chamadas ao serviço quando o mesmo demorar mais que o tempo definido no timer (no exempo 1s).

É importante lembrar que deve-se remover o subscribe no método onDestroy()  para evitar memory leaks.

```
  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.depoimentosSubscription) {
        this.depoimentosSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    if (this.timerSubscription) {
        this.timerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bruno, deu certo e atende esta sua proposta para a questão colocada, mas fiquei pensando na quantidade de requisições geradas e se isso poderia reduzir desempenho gerando desgaste na experiência do usuário. Vc conhece algum método que fizesse o contrário? Tipo só realizar uma atualização caso a base esteja diferente? Não sei se isso é possível.